# How i should add the DLL in my qt creator program?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll

When I try to open my .exe program it says: windows doesn't find the following DLL
"Qt5Widgets.dll"Qt5core"libgcc_s_seh-1.dll" any solution? Because I don't want to open qt every time
I want to use my program.

Comment: Set your windows `PATH` environment variable to include the locations where these dlls exist.

Comment: You also may want to look into: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) for information on how to deploy your applications to different machines.

Answer (score 0):

Use windeployqt.exe in qt installation directory to put necessary dlls beside your exe. In the folder that contains windeployqt.exe open cmd or powershell and run following command:

windeployqt.exe  PATH_TO_YOUR_EXE

for example:
windeployqt.exe   D:\app\foo.exe

Comment: But to share it on other pc's you have to do the same or I can put the dll's to the installer?